# Animation with emitter but out of position

Tags: gsap

I'm trying to make an animation with "L" movement (and another as flipped "L").
Here's [my code](https://codepen.io/chattago2002/pen/wvQZWNm) but is not optimized.

Animation is ok but it should follow the emitter (in my code identified by the red and green squares) instead currently animation is at the right edge.

In "createDot" function I changed the basic (from taken example)

```
document.body.appendChild(dot);
```

to

```
document.getElementById('contenitore').appendChild(dot);
```

What is going wrong? Where are my mistakes?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to adjust `relativeX` to match the changing position of the emitter within the container, you can calculate the new `relativeX` based on the bounds of the emitter and the bounds of the container. That means here finding how much the emitter has moved relative to its initial position and adjust `relativeX` accordingly.

To generalize this, you could consider saving the initial `bounds.left` value for each emitter (let's call it `initialLeft`) and then adjusting `relativeX` by the difference between `initialLeft` and the current `bounds.left`.

```js
// Save the initial position for each emitter. 
// You should do this somewhere before the animation starts.
var initialLeft = {};
initialLeft['emitter1'] = document.getElementById("emitter1").getBoundingClientRect().left;
initialLeft['emitter2'] = document.getElementById("emitter2").getBoundingClientRect().left;

// Modify shootDotCommon accordingly
function shootDotCommon(emitter) {
    // existing code

    bounds = emitter.getBoundingClientRect();

    // Calculate the displacement of the emitter along the x-axis
    var displacementX = bounds.left - initialLeft[emitter.id];

    // Calculate the relative coordinates
    var relativeX = 0 - displacementX;
    var relativeY = bounds.top - containerBounds.top + bounds.height / 2;

    // existing code
}
```

`shootDotCommon` is a function called from the `showDot()` functions:

```js
function shootDot1(emitter1) {
  shootDotCommon(emitter1);
}

function shootDot2(emitter2) {
  shootDotCommon(emitter2);
}
```

See my [codepen.io code here](https://codepen.io/vonc/pen/rNoxYBK?editors=0010).

[image: codepen.io demo]